# specify date that is one month or two month later omit the years(vba)

Tags: vba

Sub Main()

```
Dim celltxt As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
For Each cell In Range("M1:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If cell = DateAdd("m", 1, Left(Now, 10)) Then
          MsgBox "Cell matches 1 month from today at " & cell.Address
          With Selection.Font
         .Color = -16776961
         .TintAndShade = 0
         End With
End If
Next
    For Each cell In Range("M1:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If cell = DateAdd("m", 2, Left(Now, 10)) Then
        MsgBox "Cell matches 2 month from today at " & cell.Address
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

I want the system to search specify date that is one month or two month later,e.g. when i search at 11/11/2013 , actually i want all date at 11/12 (in all years) can be searched and highlight in red.
but now i can only search 11/12/2013 data , how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the day and month independently.

> Sub Main()
>
> Dim celltxt As String Dim cell As Range Dim cell2 As Range Dim
>   aMonthFromNow As Date
>
> For Each cell In Range("M1:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
>
> ```
> aMonthFromNow = DateAdd("m", 1, Now)
>
>
>
> If Month(cell) = Month(aMonthFromNow) And Day(cell) = Day(aMonthFromNow) Then
>       MsgBox "Cell matches 1 month from today at " & cell.Address
>       With Selection.Font
>      .Color = -16776961
>      .TintAndShade = 0
>      End With End If Next
> For Each cell In Range("M1:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
> If cell = DateAdd("m", 2, Left(Now, 10)) Then
>     MsgBox "Cell matches 2 month from today at " & cell.Address
> End If Next
> ```
>
> End Sub